# Finding the Variance of a Random Variable Giving PMF

Tags: probability, variance

The question is:
What’s the variance of random variable that takes values from -3 to 3 with probabilities set by PMF

$ P \quad  -3 \quad  -2 \quad  -1 \qquad  0 \quad\  1 \quad\  2 \quad  3$

$  X \qquad  \frac{1}{14} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \quad\  \frac{2}{7} \quad  \frac{2}{7} \quad  0 \quad  \frac{1}{14} $

and let me show you what I did on and keep got wrong answers. I was already found the
$\mathbb{E}X = -1/7$ then I subtract the $\mathbb{E}X$ from $X$

$ P \quad  -3 \quad  -2 \quad  -1 \qquad  0 \quad\  1 \quad\  2 \quad  3$

$  X \qquad  \frac{1}{14} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \quad\  \frac{2}{7} \quad  \frac{2}{7} \quad  0 \quad  \frac{1}{14} $

$\mathbb{E} \qquad\  \frac{3}{14} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \quad\  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{1}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{14}$

then I squared the values (for shorthand I am going to write $S$ for that row)

$ P \quad  -3 \quad  -2 \quad  -1 \qquad  0 \quad\  1 \quad\  2 \quad  3$

$  X \qquad  \frac{1}{14} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \quad\  \frac{2}{7} \quad  \frac{2}{7} \quad  0 \quad  \frac{1}{14} $

$\mathbb{E} \qquad\  \frac{3}{14} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \quad\  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{1}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{14}$

$S \qquad  \frac{9}{196} \qquad  \frac{4}{49} \quad\  \frac{4}{49} \quad\  \frac{9}{49} \quad  \frac{9}{49} \quad  \frac{1}{49} \quad  \frac{27}{196}$

Then I've multiplied with the corresponding probabilities as $M$

$ P \quad  -3 \quad  -2 \quad  -1 \qquad  0 \quad\  1 \quad\  2 \quad  3$

$  X \qquad  \frac{1}{14} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \qquad  \frac{1}{7} \quad\  \frac{2}{7} \quad  \frac{2}{7} \quad  0 \quad  \frac{1}{14} $

$\mathbb{E} \qquad\  \frac{3}{14} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \qquad  \frac{2}{7} \quad\  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{7} \quad  \frac{1}{7} \quad  \frac{3}{14}$

$S \qquad  \frac{9}{196} \qquad  \frac{4}{49} \quad\  \frac{4}{49} \quad\  \frac{9}{49} \quad  \frac{9}{49} \quad  \frac{1}{49} \quad  \frac{9}{196}$

$M \qquad  \frac{-27}{196} \qquad  \frac{-8}{49} \quad\  \frac{-4}{49} \quad\  0 \quad  \frac{9}{49} \quad  \frac{2}{49} \quad  \frac{27}{196}$

and I summed all the values and get $\frac{-1}{49}$ but this isn't acceptable. Where do I taking a wrong turn? I couldn't get around. many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the following formula

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

thus you have

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=-3\cdot\frac{1}{14}-2\cdot\frac{2}{14}-1\cdot\frac{2}{14}+1\cdot\frac{4}{14}+3\cdot\frac{1}{14}=-\frac{2}{14}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=9\cdot\frac{1}{14}+4\cdot\frac{2}{14}+1\cdot\frac{2}{14}+1\cdot\frac{4}{14}+9\cdot\frac{1}{14}=\frac{32}{14}$$

that means

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\frac{32}{14}-\frac{1}{49}=\frac{111}{49}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @tommik . The way you showed start to make much more sense.